# WebStorm FTP deployment: 'could not put ftp file'

Tags: deployment, ftp, phpstorm, webstorm

I added FTP deployment server with "Passive mode" on in WebStorm.

It runs well when downloading files from server but fails with error when uploading files:

```
[16.01.16, 13:02] Failed to transfer file '/Users/vic/sites/gulpfile.js': could not put FTP file "ftp://ver.blabla.ru/www/gulpfile.js".
```

Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can :

- change mode ftp to 'active' from 'passive'
- inspect the right of your directory FTP
- use SFTP otherwise than FTP

Comment: Thanx a lot! SFTP was the right choice for me. Manipulating with FTP was futile for unknown reason

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it by changing "Data channel protection level" in deployment host settings from "Private" to "default"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the mistake was due to

```
shell_exec
```

removed from the code and everything works

This is due to shared hosting restrictions

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while using FTPS and deactivating the option "Reuse SSL session" in the Advanced FTP Settings did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem. every so and so often the upload worked. but sometimes i got the same error described by you.

disabling TLS 1.3 under tools > deployment > configuration > advanced solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Possible situation: tmp is full

If server is Ubuntu reboot will help:

Use terminal and do this commands:

1. ssh youserver.com
2. sudo reboot

Than find solution to solve problem with tmp,
possible way: https://muras.eu/2017/12/06/apache-ubuntu-systemd-privatetmp/

1. nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service
2. find "PrivateTmp" and set it to "true"
3. restart apache and systemctl:

1. sudo systemctl restart apache2
2. systemctl daemon-reload